# How to restrict COD for certain category

Tags: opencart-3

Sorry if this topic has been asked before. I'm new with opencart. How can I configure a payment method for example Cash on Delivery with different category. 
Lets say there are 2 categories, A and B. Only Cash on Delivery is available with category A when customer wants to checkout.

What need to be changed in the cod.php? I'm using Opencart Version 3.0.3.1.

Thank you.

Found this code before which when a product has weight above 1 then disable cod.

IN:
/catalog/model/payment/cod.php

AFTER:
public function getMethod($address, $total) {

ADD:
if ($this->cart->getWeight() > 1) return;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do using this module : https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=27392

if hardcoded ok then you can add this code on :

> IN: /catalog/model/payment/cod.php

```
//category cod validation

        $VALIDATE=[1,123,12,112,346]; // add your category id here
        $products = $this->cart->getProducts();
        foreach ($products as $cart) {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT category_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category WHERE product_id = '" . (int)$cart['product_id'] . "'");
            foreach($query->rows as $cart_data){
                //array_push($check,$cart_data['category_id']);
                if( in_array($cart_data['category_id'] , $VALIDATE) )
                {
                $status=false;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: add this code before this line : "$method_data = array();"